# Why is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \ln \left(\frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)=1$?

Tags: limits

Why is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln \left(\frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)=1?$$

I see from looking at the graph that it goes to $1$ but I am not too sure how to prove this algebraically.

The only way I can see this function going to $1$ is if $(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}>n$ but I am not too sure if that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\ln\left(\frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)=\frac1n\ln\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)=\frac{a_n}n$$

and by [Stolz-Cesaro](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775085/calculting-limit-using-stolz-cesaro-theorem)

$$\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n+1-n}=\ln\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\to 1$$

Comment: Thanks Mark, ratio-root criteria has been already used thus I had to find something else! I should also become confident with Riemann sum, I'm not skilled about that method.

Comment: I like this one! Thanks

Comment: @dydxx You are welcome, it's plenty of very good answer here! It should be possible to accept multiple answers in these cases. Bye

Answer (score 4):

It is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(\ln (n)-\frac {1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln (k) \Bigr)$$

But
$$\ln (n)-\frac {1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln (k)=$$

$$-\frac {1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln \left(\frac {k}{n}\right) $$

It is a Riemann sum, its limit is
$$-\int_0^1\ln (x)dx=-\Big[x\ln (x)-x\Big]_0^1=1$$

Comment: Why is its limit what you wrote?

Comment: @zhw. The improper integral is convergent.

Comment: But such sums need not converge to the value of the integral if the improper integral exists.

Comment: @zhw. Do you have a counterexample

Comment: Yes: Tall thin triangles marching to $0.$ Your proof idea still goes through, because if $f$ is monotone, everything works. But that needs to be understood, and is worth mentioning in your proof I think.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to proving that $\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n}\to e$.

Use that if [$a_n=n^n/n!$ and $a_{n+1}/a_n\to L$ then $a_n^{1/n}\to L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287932/convergence-of-ratio-test-implies-convergence-of-the-root-test).

The limit is easier to compute using that, after simplification, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=(1+1/n)^n\to e$.

Comment: I also use often the ratio-root criteria (+1), so I had to use Casaro-Stolz in this case! (+1)

Comment: @gimusi They are the same theorem written in two forms: $a_n^{1/n}$ is the geometric mean of $a_n/a_{n-1}, a_{n-1}/a_{n-2},...,a_{2}/a_1, a_1/1$, and a geometric mean is the same as an arithmetic after taking logarithm.

Comment: @crivair Yes I know they are strictly related, indeed they lead to the same limit, but the set up and resolution come out different.

Answer (score 0):

Use the properties of the logarithm:

$\ln \frac{a}{b} = \ln a - \ln b$,

and

$\ln a^b = b \ln a$.

So we get:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(\frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}})= \ln n - \ln (n!^{1/n}) = \ln n - \frac{1}{n} \ln n! = \ln n - \frac{1}{n} n \ln n + \frac{1}{n} n = 1$

where we used Stirlings approximation: $n! \approx n \ln n  - n$ for large $n$, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html.

Comment: Maybe you should fix a littel bit the notaton and approximation used in order to make it more clear and rigorous.

Comment: fixed! Notation should be clear now.

Comment: Using limit notation you should write 

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}}\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\ln n - \ln (n!^{1/n})\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln n - \frac{1}{n} \ln n!\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\ln n - \frac{1}{n} n \ln n + \frac{1}{n} n\right) = 1$$

or in short notation

$$\ln\left(\frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}}\right)= \ln n - \ln (n!^{1/n}) = \ln n - \frac{1}{n} \ln n! \sim \ln n - \frac{1}{n} n \ln n + \frac{1}{n} n \to 1$$