# Mistake in this calculation of limits

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

I want to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n!}{n\log n}$. I know this is a duplicate and I read its equal to $1$, however I can't seem to find the problem in the below calculation:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n!}{n\log n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log1 +\log2+\dots+\log n}{n\log n}$$

Now  if we split the limits, we get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log1}{n\log n}+\dots+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{n\log n}$$

Then each term will give $0$, and thus answer should be $0$.

Comment: you cannot split the limit like that

Comment: Simple answer:  Each term has something to contribute to the total expression, but this series has *infinite number of such terms*. If there were finite number of terms then there was no problem! Also *United we stand divided we fall*.

Comment: $1 = (1/n)+ (1/n)+\cdots + (1/n)$, so $\lim _{n \to \infty} 1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} + \lim _{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} + \cdots = 0+0+\cdots = 0$.

Comment: @shiva The sum of infinitely many small term can lead to any number and also diverge, in this case the sum is 1, let try to continue the solution by Stolz-Cesaro, can you find the limit?

Comment: We know that: $$1 - \dfrac{1}{\log(n)} \leq \dfrac{\log(n!)}{n \log(n)} \leq 1$$ and when $n\to \infty$ what happens by squeez theorem?

Comment: @m_t_ That was helpful.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar I will have to read about squeez theorem. Thanks.

Comment: @shiva It is like $1 \leq x \leq 1 \to x=1$

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar How did you come up with $1 - \dfrac{1}{\log(n)} \leq \dfrac{\log(n!)}{n \log(n)}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

This method is not valide since you are summing up infintely many terms.

As an alternative refer to [Stolz-Cesaro](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775085/calculting-limit-using-stolz-cesaro-theorem)

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n!}{n\log n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log (n+1)!-\log n!}{(n+1)\log (n+1)-n\log n}$$

Comment: I got it through this theorem, I didn't know about it.

Comment: @shiva it is a kind of Hopital for sequecences, very useful indeed, Bye