# Calculate a limit using sandwich rule for sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to find the limit of sequence by using sandwich rule for sequences:

> $d = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1}}$

After a couple of operations i got to:

$n[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1}}] ≤ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}≤ n[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{1}}]$

For calculate the limit by the sandwich theorem, I've calculated the limits for both of the sides and it were different.

I'll be glad to know where is my mistake here.

Best regards.

Comment: Are you forced to use squeeze theorem?

Comment: Yes.. it seem to me a good option to calculate this limit due to my current knowledge in limits.

Comment: @OranSherif do you know Stolz-Cesaro?

Comment: No.. not yet :(

Comment: @OranSherif I add an answer by this as reference for an alternative approach. Squeeze theorem not alway is simple to apply since we need to find one or two good bound terms. Iwill take a look also to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that yours is a telescoping sum
$$d = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}}{2}$$

The intermediate terms cancel and only last and first terms are left. The sum therefore is: $$\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: I didn't got it how you got to the last sum, and how exact the sigma "gone"

Comment: @oran its the magic of telescope. Write a few terms. Numerator will have $\sqrt{3}-1 + (\sqrt 5 - \sqrt{3}) + (\sqrt{7}- \sqrt 5)$ ... In each step, intermediate terms get cancelled and only end terms remain

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

As an alternative by [Stolz-Cesaro](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775085/calculting-limit-using-stolz-cesaro-theorem)

$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1}}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+3}+\sqrt{2n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}$$