# Find the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+2^{1/2}+3^{1/3}+\cdots+n^{1/n}}{n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

The given problem is a problem of calculus. I have tried this problem only to find that the numerator is a divergent series. No idea how to do this problem

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+2^{1/2}+3^{1/3}+\cdots+n^{1/n}}{n}$$

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

By [Stolz-Cesaro](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775085/calculting-limit-using-stolz-cesaro-theorem)

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^\frac1k}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\quad (n+1)^{\frac1{n+1}}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove in general that if $a_n\to a$ as $n\to \infty$, then
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{a_i}{n}\to a
$$
as well. Now note that $\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$, and you're done.